# Making ios app with simular icon

Tags: ios

I published one my app to store.

Now I want to create a little bit different version of that app and publish it as separate app. (For the common account)

I will extend the app's features
Can I use simular icon? or which staff I need to replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case I use a different icon, bundle id, and different app description. Everything else were the same. If you're not sure if there's anything more to change just submit the app for review and apple will reply if there's anything more to change.

Comment: yup, new bundle id is mandatory. Did you post this update long time ago?

Comment: It's just a week ago.